# The method 'data' isn't defined for the type 'Object'. Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'data'

Tags: firebase, flutter

I have issues to display data from Firebase. Here is the code I used in my FutureBuilder. Looks like there is an error regarding data(), but I don't know which one, does anyone have any idea?

This is what I get : "The method 'data' isn't defined for the type 'Object'.
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'data'."

```
if(snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
  Map<String, dynamic> documentData = snapshot.data!.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
     return ListView(
       children: [

         CustomSubtitle(
           text: "${documentData['01 - Brand']}"
         ),

         CustomTitle(
           text: "${documentData['02 - Name']}",
         ),

         CustomText(
          text: "${documentData['04 - Description']}",
         )

       ],
     );
   }
```

Comment: ` Map<String, dynamic> documentData = snapshot.data as Map<String, dynamic>;`

Comment: Oops... My code is ok now, but when I run the App, I've got an error "type '_JsonDocumentSnapshot' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic> in type cast". Do you have an idea ?

Comment: yes, I re -read you r code a few times and realized that you should change your if condition to if(snapshot.hasData && !(snapshot.hasError)) {...}. I am assuming that this function is a part of the builder in a FutureBuilder widget.

Comment: Yes, thank you I've found the solution. Thank for your time and your help !

Comment: No problem at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If someone is in my case, I've found the solution :

```
builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<DocumentSnapshot> snapshot) {

    if(snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
    DocumentSnapshot<Object?> documentData = snapshot.data!;
     return ListView(
       children: [

           CustomSubtitle(
             text: "${documentData['01 - Brand']}"
           ),

           CustomTitle(
             text: "${documentData['02 - Name']}",
           ),

           CustomText(
             text: "${documentData['04 - Description']}",
           )

         ],
       );
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using code for a `QuerySnapshot`. For such one your code would work but considering how you use the resulting data you received a `DocumentSnapshot`. For that to work just change your code to this:

```
if(snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
  Map<String, dynamic> documentData = snapshot.data as Map<String, dynamic>;
     return ListView(
       children: [

         CustomSubtitle(
           text: "${documentData['01 - Brand']}"
         ),

         CustomTitle(
           text: "${documentData['02 - Name']}",
         ),

         CustomText(
          text: "${documentData['04 - Description']}",
         )

       ],
     );
   }
```

Comment: Thank you !! Actually, it's work when I remove the () after data :)

Answer (score 0):

```
  future: collection.doc(documentId).get(),
  builder: ((context, snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
      Map<String, dynamic> data =
          snapshot.data!.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
      String currency = '${data['currency']}';
      
      return  Material(
          )
```